# Как решить проблему с оптимизации карт от Яндекса?

Tags: оптимизация, яндекс-карты, оптимизация-сайтов

недавно столкнулся с одной проблемой. Был лендинг, там было 2 карты от яндекс maps. Поставил через script(src... ) в коде. Все отлично работало пока я не стал проверять сайт на оптимизацию. Показатели Google 30. Я начал оптимизировать изображение и.тп, но добился лишь жалких 40. И не мог понять в чем дело. Пока не сделал еще один запрос через GtMetrix, и посмотрел что самые последние грузились яндекс карты. Ради теста убрал
Показатели гугла повысились до 89
GtMetrix 90 , 90
Скорость загрузки снизилась в 2 раза
Запросы с 190 уменьшились до 110

Думаю очевидна что такая большая разница очень сильно влияет на скорость загрузки.
Сейчас у меня проект где на странице 3 карты будут( Разные адресы, и через табы будут переключатся карты)
У меня вопрос как оптимизировать это дело что бы яндекс не грузил с собой еще 80 доп скриптов . Как вы оптимизируйте, ибо яндекс карта очень большая потребность

Comment: Карты грузятся асинхронно. Но гугл всё равно будет ругаться на скорость. Последний их алгоритм совсем глупым стал. Он даже на счётчик гугл аналитики ругается..... Без счётчика 95, со счётчиком 40.....

Comment: Все равно полная загрузка сайта в 2 раза меньше без карт

Comment: Карты грузятся асинхронно. Сайтом пользователь может пользоваться, ну а карты пусть потом до загружаются... не вижу в этом проблемы. Таже ситуация и с JivoSite и с метрикой. Если их выключить, то сайт очень быстро по показателям грузится. Ну попробуйте гугл-карты.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Только заказчик проверяет, и видит цифру что полная загрузка страницы 12 секунд...